# Wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass

My application is breaking and I can't figure out why. Here is the full system stack trace.

```
sass (3.4.9) lib/sass/importers/filesystem.rb:14:in `initialize'
compass-rails (2.0.1) lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:12:in `new'
compass-rails (2.0.1) lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:12:in `block in evaluate'
compass-rails (2.0.1) lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:12:in `map'
compass-rails (2.0.1) lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:12:in `evaluate'
tilt (1.4.1) lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:75:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.3) lib/sprockets/base.rb:295:in `[]'
sprockets-rails (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:230:in `lookup_asset_for_path'
sprockets-rails (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:190:in `check_errors_for'
sprockets-rails (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:159:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
sprockets-rails (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:158:in `map'
sprockets-rails (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:158:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__741030643_51172800'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:67:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
eventmachine-1.0.3-x86 (mingw32) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine-1.0.3-x86 (mingw32) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (>= 0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      sass (~> 3.2.2) x86-mingw32

    foundation-rails (>= 0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      sass (3.4.9)
```

GEM FILE [UPDATED]

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'qrcode'
gem 'sunspot'
gem 'foundation-rails', '~> 5.4.5.0'
gem 'seed-fu'
gem 'letsrate'
gem 'resque'
gem 'link_thumbnailer'
gem 'premailer'
gem 'mailcatcher'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'fastimage', '~> 1.6.4'
gem 'grape'
gem 'grape-swagger'
gem 'doorkeeper'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'devise'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'devise_security_extension'
gem 'compass', '~> 1.0.1'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'fullcalendar-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 2.12.3'
gem 'railties'
gem 'ratyrate'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'sass', '~> 3.4.9'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.5.3'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.2.5'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.1',          group: :doc

GEMfile.lock [UPDATED]

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.8)
      actionpack (= 4.1.8)
      actionview (= 4.1.8)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.8)
      actionview (= 4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activemodel (4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.8)
      activemodel (= 4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.8)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.3.6)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    axiom-types (0.1.1)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.4)
      ice_nine (~> 0.11.0)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
    bcrypt (3.1.9-x86-mingw32)
    builder (3.2.2)
    chunky_png (1.3.3)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.5)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coercible (1.0.0)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.1)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
    compass (1.0.1)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      compass-core (~> 1.0.1)
      compass-import-once (~> 1.0.5)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
      sass (>= 3.3.13, < 3.5)
    compass-core (1.0.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      sass (>= 3.3.0, < 3.5)
    compass-import-once (1.0.5)
      sass (>= 3.2, < 3.5)
    compass-rails (2.0.1)
      compass (~> 1.0.0)
    countries (0.9.3)
      currencies (~> 0.4.2)
    country_select (2.1.0)
      countries (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.3)
    css_parser (1.3.5)
      addressable
    currencies (0.4.2)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
    devise (3.4.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise_security_extension (0.8.0)
      devise (>= 2.0.0)
      rails (>= 3.1.1)
    doorkeeper (2.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    equalizer (0.0.9)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.3-x86-mingw32)
    execjs (2.2.2)
    fastimage (1.6.6)
      addressable (~> 2.3, >= 2.3.5)
    ffi (1.9.6-x86-mingw32)
    foundation-rails (5.4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.2.0)
    friendly_id (5.0.4)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    fullcalendar-rails (2.2.3.0)
      jquery-rails (>= 3.1.1, < 5.0.0)
      momentjs-rails (~> 2.8, >= 2.8.3)
    gmaps4rails (2.1.2)
    grape (0.9.0)
      activesupport
      builder
      hashie (>= 2.1.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.3.2)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
      rack (>= 1.3.0)
      rack-accept
      rack-mount
      virtus (>= 1.0.0)
    grape-entity (0.4.4)
      activesupport
      multi_json (>= 1.3.2)
    grape-swagger (0.8.0)
      grape
      grape-entity
    haml (4.0.6)
      tilt
    hashie (3.3.2)
    hike (1.2.3)
    htmlentities (4.3.2)
    i18n (0.6.11)
    ice_nine (0.11.1)
    jbuilder (2.2.5)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (3.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-turbolinks (2.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
      turbolinks
    json (1.8.1)
    letsrate (1.0.9)
    link_thumbnailer (2.3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      fastimage (~> 1.6)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      net-http-persistent (~> 2.9)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rake (>= 0.9)
      video_info (~> 2.3)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mailcatcher (0.2.4)
      eventmachine
      haml
      i18n
      json
      mail
      sinatra
      skinny (>= 0.1.2)
      sqlite3-ruby
      thin
    mime-types (2.4.3)
    mini_portile (0.6.1)
    minitest (5.5.0)
    momentjs-rails (2.8.3)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    mono_logger (1.1.0)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    net-http-persistent (2.9.4)
    nokogiri (1.6.5-x86-mingw32)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (4.2.1)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.3)
      mime-types
    pr_geohash (1.0.0)
    premailer (1.8.2)
      css_parser (>= 1.3.5)
      htmlentities (>= 4.0.0)
    qrcode (0.0.1)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-accept (0.4.5)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.8)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.8)
      actionpack (= 4.1.8)
      actionview (= 4.1.8)
      activemodel (= 4.1.8)
      activerecord (= 4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.8)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.1.8)
      actionpack (= 4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    ratyrate (1.2.2.alpha)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
    rb-inotify (0.9.5)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
    recaptcha (0.3.6)
    redis (3.2.0)
    redis-namespace (1.5.1)
      redis (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.4)
    responders (1.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 4.2)
    resque (1.25.2)
      mono_logger (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      redis-namespace (~> 1.3)
      sinatra (>= 0.9.2)
      vegas (~> 0.1.2)
    rsolr (1.0.10)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    sass (3.4.9)
    sass-rails (5.0.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    seed-fu (2.3.3)
      activerecord (>= 3.1, < 4.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.1, < 4.2)
    simple_form (3.1.0)
      actionpack (~> 4.0)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
    sinatra (1.4.5)
      rack (~> 1.4)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.4)
    skinny (0.2.3)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0.0)
      thin (~> 1.5.0)
    sprockets (2.12.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.10-x86-mingw32)
    sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
      sqlite3 (>= 1.3.3)
    sunspot (2.1.1)
      pr_geohash (~> 1.0)
      rsolr (~> 1.0.7)
    thin (1.5.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2014.10)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uglifier (2.6.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    vegas (0.1.11)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    video_info (2.4.0)
      addressable
      htmlentities
      multi_json
    virtus (1.0.3)
      axiom-types (~> 0.1)
      coercible (~> 1.0)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.3)
      equalizer (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.9)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  compass (~> 1.0.1)
  compass-rails
  country_select
  devise
  devise_security_extension
  doorkeeper
  fastimage (~> 1.6.4)
  foundation-rails (~> 5.4.5.0)
  friendly_id
  fullcalendar-rails
  gmaps4rails
  grape
  grape-swagger
  jbuilder (~> 2.2.5)
  jquery-rails
  jquery-turbolinks
  letsrate
  link_thumbnailer
  mailcatcher
  paperclip
  premailer
  qrcode
  rails (= 4.1.8)
  railties
  ratyrate
  recaptcha
  resque
  sass-rails (~> 5.0.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.1)
  seed-fu
  simple_form
  sprockets (~> 2.12.3)
  sqlite3
  sunspot
  turbolinks (~> 2.5.3)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```

Help, please? It was working 1 hour ago. I added a jquery for turbolinks, and then everything went up in flames.

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: I've updated to include the contents of my full gem file.

Comment: Any chance your project is under git or subversion? How did you add the new gem, which command did you run?

Comment: I'm running Bonobo on a local server.

Comment: I did a basic install with the console.

Comment: Sass-rails 5.0 is not compatible with sass 3.4.  It is listed as requiring sass 3.1 (see: https://rubygems.org/gems/sass-rails)

Comment: You mention you added Jquery-turbolinks and things went wrong. If you comment those lines out, do things un-blow-up?

Comment: I uninstalled jquery-turbolinks. That doesn't seem to be the issue. It's something wrong with sass, compass and sprockets. They're at the very top of the stack trace.

Answer (score 5):

```
gem 'sass-rails', github: 'rails/sass-rails', branch: '4-0-stable'
```

That saved my day. I hope it helps you too.

If this does not work then try:

```
rake assets:clean
```

I guess the problem is the new version of Sass is not compatible with something in Rails application.

Answer (score 0):

try commenting out this line in your Gemfile and running `bundle update`:

`gem 'sass', '~> 3.4.9'`

EDIT:

Incompatibility between sass-rails and foundation-rails over the sass version.  I would recommend not using sass-rails 5 as it is a new release ahead of Rails 5.  Remove explicit declaration of Sass in Gemfile and change sass-rails version to 4.0.5

Comment: I commented out this file, but the error remains the same. I tried using the older version of sass Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass":
  In Gemfile:
    sass (~> 3.1.0) x86-mingw32

    compass (~> 1.0.1) x86-mingw32 depends on
      sass (3.3.13)

Comment: Sass should be brought in by sass-rails, so there is absolutely no reason to include in the Gemfile.  Can you post your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: Same goes for compass and compass-rails.

Comment: I added the gemfile.lock underneath the gem file so that you can see what's inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Sprockets was installed twice for some reason. I installed sprockets-rails 2.2.2 to replace the stand-alone Sprockets gem. I also removed the dependencies that tagCincy brought up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with compass-rails, using sprockets 2.12.3 was one of the solutions, but now this works with the latest gems.

```
gem 'compass-rails', github: 'Compass/compass-rails', branch: 'master'
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing compass from my gemfile (remember `bundle install`) and then using the new sprockets beta fixed it for me.

`gem "sprockets", "~>3.0.0.beta"` in gemfile. Then `bundle update sprockets`.

Enjoy :)